# Want to render superfish_menu_tree in main_menu_tree place dupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

Sir, I have a main menu rendered in page.tpl.php

```
<div class="menu_wrapper">
  <nav id="main-menu"  role="navigation">
    <a class="nav-toggle" href="#">Navigation</a>
    <div class="menu-navigation-container">
      <?php print drupal_render($main_menu_tree); ?>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </nav>
```

In which here rendered main_menu_tree, i want to replace this page with my superfish menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use block_load as follows, replace

```
<?php print drupal_render($main_menu_tree); ?>
```

with

```
<?php 
$block = block_load('superfish', 1);
$output = render(_block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block))));
print $output;
?>
```

Comment: thnks sir for answering me.